# Does SHCreateItemFromParsingName() need full path?

Tags: shell, winapi, com

I want to process files via `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()` and then get a IShellItem for each file so that I have wildcard support.   It looks like I would use `SHCreateItemFromParsingName()` but it seems I would have to build a full path each time before passing the file name to it?

I saw a oldnewthing sample that created a fake file by using a helper function `CreateFileSysBindCtx()` for a WIN32_FIND_DATA structure and passing that as the second parameter to `SHCreateItemFromParsingName()` so wonder if that can be done for files found via `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()` where just the filename is passed and the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` results and it can create the `IShellItem`?

Or maybe there is a better way to get from the `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()` to something I can use to populate a `IResultsFolder`.

TIA!!

Comment: `SHCreateItemFromRelativeName` lets you use one `IShellItem` as the parent, which would probably be more efficient than parsing the full path for every file.

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to perform the filtering in your code instead of mixing shell and file system code. Then your code would be able to work with non file system shell items.

Comment: Yes, `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` needs full path. And `GetFullPathName(win32_find_data.cFileName, MAX_PATH, fullpath, lppPart);` can easily get the full path through the filename.

Comment: If you want to search files with wildcard, you can use _ISearchFolderItemFactory_ (used by Explorer)